# Python access and iterate over values in dataframe that includes a list

Tags: python, dataframe, apply

I have a dataset of newspaper articles that looks like this:

```
data =  [[1, "Blah blah blah", ['according to','says']],
         [2, "Blah blah blah", ['','']],
         [3, "Blah blah blah", ['acknowledges']]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['id', 'text', 'words']
```

Obviously the column `df['text']` has the real text of the article.

I would like to iterate over `df['words']` and delete the word from the list once it has been found in `df['text']`.

Can someone please show me to iterate over the list in the dataframe ? I was thinking of using the `apply()` function.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
data =  [[1, "Blah blah blah", ['according to','says']],
         [2, "Blah blah blah", ['b','blah']],
         [3, "Blah blah blah", ['acknowledges']]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['id', 'text', 'words']
for Index, (x, i) in enumerate(zip(df['text'], df['words'])):
    for j in i.copy():
        if " "+j+" " in " "+x+" ":
            df['words'][Index].remove(j)
```

Comment: Thanks John ! It works for words without any space character, but 'according to' is not getting deleted, even though I replaced 'blah blah blah' by a generic sentence containing the word. Any idea why the space character might cause trouble ? the encoding maybe ?

Comment: How about this new one?

Comment: Now it works for 'according this', but the code only deletes the first word in the list. Hence, 'says' is not deleted. I've tried by adding more words in the last row as well and the result is the same.

Comment: I already did but because I have less than 15 reputation it says my vote won't affect the publicly displayed post score

Comment: ah, now I get it. Thanks again

Comment: Thank you to. :)